# db2 crash with db2 force application command

Tags: database, db2

We have installed db2 on Linux Power machine.
DB2 level is 11.1.4.4.
I have kill single session with "db2 force application (agent_id)", and it crashed database.

We have observed that this is 3rd time, when we kill single session, it downs database.

Answer (score 0):

Best to raise this with IBM Support

You can also look at the db2diag.log for more information about the crash

Comment: we have engage the IBM support, but still looking for the root cause

Comment: out of interest, what is the application doing when you force it?

Answer (score 0):

For migration data from Oracle to db2, if wrapper is set to 'N' and when we kill the session which is pooling data from Oracle, it was shutdown the database, so after contacting with DB2 support, they suggest that the Oracle wrapper (net8) option db2_fenced should be change to 'Y' (e.g alter wrapper net8 options (set db2_fenced 'Y')

Comment: Can you edit these contents in your previous answer https://superuser.com/a/1462637/174140?

Answer (score -1):

For migration data from Oracle to db2, if wrapper is set to 'N' and when we kill the session which is pooling data from Oracle, it was shutdown the database, so after contacting with DB2 support, they suggest that the Oracle wrapper (net8) option db2_fenced should be change to 'Y' (e.g alter wrapper net8 options (set db2_fenced 'Y')

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so and **where** this change needs to be made.